# Authorization in Pycharm for using a Google BigQuery dataset

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, authorization

This is the code that I am running in Pycharm to access a public dataset on Google Cloud. I add my code in case it helps to understand the problem better. When I run this code, I get a URL in the output to authorize the application and the output waits for the authorization code to be entered. But when I click on the link, I get this error:

> Access blocked: This app’s request is invalid. You can’t sign in because this app sent an invalid request. You can try again later, or contact the developer about this issue. If you are a developer of this app, see error details. Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch".

```
import pandas
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.oauth2 import service_account

key_path = "tornado.json"

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(key_path, scopes = ["http://googleapis.com/auth/bigquery"])

project_id = 'tornado'

client = bigquery.Client(credentials = credentials, project=credentials.project_id)


Filename = 'deposits.csv'

df = pandas.io.gbq.read_gbq(

    '''
    
    SELECT *
    
    FROM bigquery-public-data.crypto_ethereum.transactions
    
    WHERE to_address = '0x12d66f87a04a9e220743712ce6d9bb1b5616b8fc'
    
    ''',

    project_id=project_id, dialect='standard'

)

df.to_csv(Filename, index=False)
```

I've read the solutions in similar posts in stackflow, they suggest adding the redirect uri in the APIs and Services/Credentials, then adding the url in OAuth 2.0 Client IDs. When creating a new credential (OAuth client ID) I select Web application since its the only one that has the option to add "authorized redirect URIs". But I don't know what should I add there.

Comment: I recommend to not use key file, but use ADC. On your environment, perform a `gcloud auth application-default login`. logs with your own account. Then the google cloud client library will detect automatically your credential and use it to log you in. It's more secure and you won't have all these questions!